# How to detect that C# Windows Forms code is executed within Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a variable or a preprocessor constant that allows to know that the code is executed within the context of Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you want this information to know if your code it being debugged? If yes there is a macro which tells you if a debugger is attached to your application refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188201/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-debugger-is-attached-to-a-process-from-c

Comment: In C# you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361077/c-clr-remote-debugger-how-to-wait-until-attached

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try [**Debugger.IsAttached**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) or [**DesignMode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property or get [**ProcessName**](http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2005/04/11/1246.aspx) or a combination, as appropriate

```
Debugger.IsAttached // or                                       
LicenseUsageMode.Designtime // or 
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
```

Here is a [**sample**](http://voidnish.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/checking-for-design-mode/)

```
public static class DesignTimeHelper {
    public static bool IsInDesignMode {
        get {
            bool isInDesignMode = LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime || Debugger.IsAttached == true;

            if (!isInDesignMode) {
                using (var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()) {
                    return process.ProcessName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("devenv");
                }
            }

            return isInDesignMode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont forget the crazy memory leak on Process.GetCurrentProcess() remember to dispose

Comment: In my code, I've added a static bool variable to know when IsInDesignMode was called and another one to hold the result of the function. At the beginning of the function, I return the result of the first call. With this, the inner of the function is just call once in design time and once at runtime. I don't see any conflict where the design time is merge with the runtime and this is much faster when you have a huge number of calls to this function.

Comment: This does not differentiate between running the VS Designer/preview and running the app with the debugger attached.

Answer (score 18):

The DesignMode property isn't always accurate. We have had use this method so that it works consistently:

```
    protected new bool DesignMode
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.DesignMode)
                return true;

            return LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;
        }
    }
```

The context of your call is important. We've had DesignMode return false in the IDE if running in an event under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

There is the [`DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property for Components. It is handy when you use the Design Viewer of VS.

But when you talk about debugging in Visual Studio you need to use the [`Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) property. Then, you can use

```
#if DEBUG
#endif
```

too

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest and most reliable way to determine if your extension is executed in the WinForms designer is to check the current process.

```
public static bool InVisualStudio() {
  return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(
    "devenv", 
    Process.CurrentProcess.ProcessName);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this extension method:

```
internal static class ControlExtension
{
    public static bool IsInDesignMode(this Control control)
    {
        while (control != null)
        {
            if (control.Site != null && control.Site.DesignMode)
                return true;
            control = control.Parent;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a DesignMode property that you can check but in my experience it's not always accurate. You could also check to see if the executable is DevEnv.exe

Take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664/designmode-with-controls). Might make this question a dup but it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
protected static bool IsInDesigner
{
    get { return (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() == null); }
}
```

Comment: False positive returned during Excel VSTO dialog coding.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to distinguish whether it's running in Visual Studio or if it's deployed to customers.

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) {
    // do stuff 
} else {
   // do stuff (within Visual Studio)
}
```

Works fine for me for ages. I skip some logic when inside Visual Studio (such as logging in to application etc).

Comment: Doesn't that presume [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) is used (disguised in Visual Studio as "Publish")? Would it work if a setup project is used to produce an ordinary [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer?

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to this that in Visual Studio 2022 with .Net 6, the process that actually opens winforms designers is called [DesignToolsServer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/state-of-the-windows-forms-designer-for-net-applications/).

`DesignMode` works outside of the constructor and checking for `ProcessName = "DesignToolsServer"` works within the constructor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).