# How to programmatically discover whether the running application is installed?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I want the program to check if it's installed on the computer (using Clickonce) or just being run (e.g. by Visual Studio).

EDIT: Not a duplicate of [How to detect that C# Windows Forms code is executed within Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427381/how-to-detect-that-c-sharp-winform-code-is-executed-within-visual-studio) . "e.g." means [for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exempli_gratia).

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain why? Obvious answer? (Well, I don't know it.) Easily found by searching? (try it first. I did.)

Comment: (Not the downvoter) Is this a website or a winforms application? If the latter, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427381/how-to-detect-that-c-sharp-winform-code-is-executed-within-visual-studio

Comment: @BobKaufman Added tag - Winforms. (Does it matter?)

Comment: @BobKaufman Thanks. You can transform your comment into an answer. Although I'll still be waiting for a direct way for finding if it's installed - your answer's surely worth an upvote. I didn't realize `Debugger.IsAttached` would be `true` even if the Solution Configuration is Release.

Comment: thanks for the offer, but I can't take credit for another's work. If one of the answers in that question helped you, by all means upvote that answer! :)

Comment: @BobKaufman, I wish you'd put your last comment as an answer and I'd upvote it, that is really becoming a problem. For whatever reason SO has become a competition rather than a community it seems.

Comment: There isn't a single way.  You could check to see if the virtual hosting process was running and/or if Visual Studio itself is running.

Comment: @Ramhound See Maarten's answer. ("e.g." means [for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exempli_gratia).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed.aspx) property. Please note that this only works with ClickOnce installations.

```
private void CheckApplicationStatus() {
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) {
        // Do something that needs doing when the application is installed using ClickOnce.
    } else {
        // Do something that needs doing when the application is run from VS.
    }
}
```