# Dynamically get paths to project-folders in ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

**The problem**: Clickonce puts sub-folders of a project in a different place when used in Visual Studio vs when installed as a Clickonce application.

**In Visual Studio** they are under:

```
Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent
```

While **when installed**, they're under:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Though I can check for Clickonce installation (as shown in an answer to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919784/how-to-programmatically-discover-whether-the-running-application-is-installed)  , "closed as not a real question"...) I'm worried this might break at some point - unless I understand exactly *why* this happens.

So what’s the **correct** way of getting folders' paths both when running inside Visual Studio, and when installed as Clickonce?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, try to use `Application.StartupPath` and `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` as follows:

```
string startupPath = ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
    ? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory :
    : Application.StartupPath;
```

Or just `Application.StartupPath`.

Or just `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory`.

It depends on the meaning of the "Clickonce puts sub-folders of a project"

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try these. As for what I meant, here's a simple example: In my project I have a folder, `Folder1`. In it there is a file `Text1.txt` and I want my application to get its path so it can read its content.

Comment: Definitely use `Application.StartupPath` if you included this folder in the deploying package.

Comment: Nope. Works when installed as Clickonce. But not when executed in VS.

Comment: (I'm also looking into how I can tell Clickonce that they're data files. Currently I have these files as `Build Action` = `Content` simply because that's how it's done automatically.)

Comment: Does the folder copied into the build output folder when running in VS?

Comment: If you mean ".../bin/debug" - No. It doesn't.

Comment: But its files copied, aren't they?
If so, they should be accessible via `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Text1.txt")` when running in VS too.