# Inherited Windows Form strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

On the load of a form, I need to do `X` amount of check's to determine whether or not to open or close the form. The below is a simple example.

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
  private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if(!IsUserValid())
      MessageBox.Show("User is not valid");
  }
  private bool IsUserValid()
  {
    List<string> allowedUsernames = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
      //Get a list of usernames, none of which are "Developer" usernames
    }
    return allowedUsernames.Any(username => username == Environment.UserName);
  }
}
public partial class DerivedForm : BaseForm
{

}
```

The example above, I can load the form perfectly in the designer regardless of my username. If I do another form, `DerivedForm` and inherit base then it calls `Load` and therefore will show a `MessageBox` and then `Close` the form in design mode which doesn't give me access to the designer, why does a derived `WindowsForm` need to use the `Load` event but the base doesn't? If you are doing inheritence with `WindowsForms` would it be wise just to not use the Load event?

I just thought this was weird, anyone know?

Comment: I don't see `override`.  Where do you hook the load event?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey There isn't an `override` just a direct inherit from derived to the base.

Comment: Consider separating business logic from UI. Form should not contain method named `IsUserValid` - move it to the engine class and call it on it and then, depending on the result, decide whether or not to create (and display) form.

Comment: @BojanKomazec I know that I should put my logic in a class, this was just done for the pure simplicity of example code and replicating the problem.

Comment: "Consider separating business logic from UI", also consider using a framework that actually allows for such a thing, such as WPF.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, first close all the open documents in VS. First, open `BaseForm` in designer, then open `DerivedForm` in designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427381/how-to-detect-that-c-sharp-winform-code-is-executed-within-visual-studio) which addresses a similar issue. Also, the accepted answer gives a solution to overcome this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427420/674700.

Basically, in your case, add the `DesignTimeHelper` class and just use the following modification to see the difference:

```
private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!DesignTimeHelper.IsInDesignMode)
    {
        if (!IsUserValid())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User is not valid");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Called from VS");
    }
}
```