# Remote Debugging, attach to process that isn't started yet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I have a console application that is triggered by an event in the database. This application runs in under a second and exits awaiting the next trigger. I'm having an issue on the server that I cannot replicate on my dev machine so need to remotely debug the application on the server.

How can I attach to the process to remotely debug this application when the process is so short lived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the program wait for a keypress or other external event before continuing. While it's waiting, you can attach the debugger.

Alternatively, let the program wait until the debugger is attached, see [How to wait until remote .NET debugger attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361077/how-to-wait-until-remote-net-debugger-attached).